# How can I improve what I already have?

Tags: python, function, speed-test

I have created a windows internet speed test, I'd like to improve it and make the code more presentable as well as better define my functions.

When the computer reaches initialise, due to the variable being in another function, it cannot call it. How can I rectify this as I have various variables being called in different functions.

Feel free to use this speedtester as well, I will be working on developing a useful phone app to run the code as well.

The code prints the current date and time, searches for the connected SSID, initialises the speedtest module, scans for servers, selects the best server, initiates ping test, then download speed test, then upload speed test, followed by printing the results on screen and writing it to a simple txt file for viewing later.

Each function shows its run time using the time module and lastly total execution time with date and time also.

It works perfectly without the functions, and on android without find_ssid(): but I keep running into the trouble of localised variables.

import speedtest
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import re
import time

def main():

```
def date():
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    dtn = dt_now.strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y, %H:%M:%S%p")
    return dtn
print(date())



def find_ssid():
    stt = time.time()
    cdop = subprocess.run(["netsh", "WLAN", "show", "interfaces"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
    ssid = (re.findall("SSID                   : (.*)\r", cdop))
    for char in ssid:
        ssid = f"Network Name: {char} \n"
    sid = time.time() - stt
    print(f'SSID found in: {sid:.2f}s')
    print(ssid)
find_ssid()


def initialise():
    print("Initialising network speed test... ")
    st = speedtest.Speedtest()
    print("Network speed test active.")
    sta = time.time() - stt
    print(f'Speed test activation time: {sta - sid:.2f}s')


def scan_servers():
    print("Scanning for available servers...")
    st.get_servers()
    print("Found available servers.")
    sft = time.time() - stt
    print(f'Servers found in: {sft - sta:.2f}s')


def best_server():
    print("Choosing best server...")
    bserv = st.get_best_server()
    print(f"Best server is: {bserv['sponsor']} - {bserv['host']} located in {bserv['name']}, {bserv['country']}")
    bst = time.time() - stt
    print(f'Best server found in: {bst - sft:.2f}s')


def ping_test():
    print("Ping testing...")
    p = st.results.ping
    ph = f"Ping: {p:.2f}ms"
    print("Ping test complete.")
    ptt = time.time() - stt
    print(f'Ping test completed in: {ptt - bst:.2f}s')


def download_speed_test():
    print("Download speed testing...")
    ds = st.download()
    dsh = f"Download speed: {ds / 1024 / 1024:.2f}mb/s"
    print("Download speed test complete.")
    dst = time.time() - stt
    print(f'Download speed test completed in: {dst - ptt:.2f}s')


def upload_speed_test():
    print("Upload speed testing...")
    us = st.upload()
    ust = time.time() - stt
    ush = f"Upload speed: {us / 1024 / 1024:.2f}mb/s \n"
    print("Upload speed test complete. \n")
    print(f'Upload speed test completed in: {ust - dst:.2f}s')


def result():
    print("Speed test results are: \n")
    print(ssid)
    print(ph)
    print(dsh)
    print(ush)

    ttn = datetime.now()
    fdt = ttn.strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y, %H:%M:%S%p")
    tt = time.time() - stt
    print(f"Start Time: {dtn}")
    print(f"Finish Time: {fdt}")
    print(f'Total execution time: {tt:.2f}s')

    results = [ssid, ph, dsh, ush, dtn]
    txt = "Speedtest Results.txt"

    with open(txt, 'a') as f:
        f.write("\n")
        f.write("\n".join(results))
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

You can run this on, one line i believe by

```
 ssid = (re.findall("SSID                   : (.*)\r", cdop))
    for char in ssid:
        ssid = f"Network Name: {char} \n/
```

Which should make it quicker, have a look at list comprehension